# To Read Full LaTeX File using LaTeX2e Macros

Tags: macros

I am new in LaTeX Platform (learning) and would like to read full LaTeX file using LaTeX2e Macros and will do some replacements.

My MWE is:

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{ragged2e}
        
        \begin{document}
        \title{Book Title}
        \author{Author Name}
        \maketitle
        
    To address these issues, \textit{WordMelodies} a mobile application to support children in the acquisition of basic literacy skills.
    The app was designed to be inclusive for children with and without VIB, thus promoting interaction between them.
    \textit{WordMelodies} also supports children in exercising basic touchscreen interactions on mobile devices.
    
    \begin{quote}
        The AI for the expected number of XXXX to ZZZZ transitive triads is generally very narrow. Since this statistic reflects relatively high-order structures (because more ties are involved), its range of possible values given the number of edge counts or mutual.
    \end{quote}    
    
    We previously presented a evaluation with visual impairments to assess app usability and accessibility XXXX and ZZZZ.
    Study results unveiled that the app is indeed accessible and usable by people with VIB.
    After the publication remote collection of app usage data, aiming to investigate how end users interact with the system.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{bib1}
Author N., ``Revisiting the Foundations of Network Analysis,'' {\em Science}, {325},~414--416.

\bibitem{bib2}
------ ``Diagnosing Multicollinearity Random Graph Models,'' {\em Research}, {50},~491--530.

\end{thebibliography}
    
    \end{document}
```

Required:

1. If `LaTeX` file is having `XXXX` text I would like to get `LaTeX Compile Error` like `LateX Error?`.
2. If `LaTeX` file is having `ZZZZ` text I would like to change `\texttt{ZZZZ}`.
3. If `LaTeX` file is having `------` in `\begin{thebibliography}...\end{thebibliography}` text I would like to get `LaTeX Compile Error` like `LateX Error?`.

How to do using `LaTeX` only and not use of `XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX`?

Thanking in you advance and your support.

My bibliography Macro:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \bibsection
 \parindent\z@
 \bibpreamble
 \bibfont
 \list{\@biblabel{\the\c@NAT@ctr}}{\@bibsetup{#1}\global\c@NAT@ctr\z@}%
 \ifNAT@openbib
   \renewcommand\newblock{\par}%
 \else
   \renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}%
 \fi
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.\@m
 \let\NAT@bibitem@first@sw\@firstoftwo
    \let\citeN\cite \let\shortcite\cite
    \let\citeasnoun\cite
}{%
 \bibitem@fin
 \bibpostamble
 \def\@noitemerr{%
  \PackageWarning{natbib}{Empty `thebibliography' environment}%
 }%
 \endlist
 \bibcleanup
}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome! You've tagged this `latex3`, but your question specifies LaTeX2e. It is also not clear how you mean this to be done using 'LaTeX macros' or what you mean by 'Plain LaTeX'. What you seem to be asking is not a sensible approach. If you were prepared to type `\XXXX` and `\YYYY`, it would obviously be different. It would also be different if you wanted to use external tools to preprocess the file. But it is not sensible to scan the entire contents of the `document` environment for arbitrary sequences of letters. I mean you *could* redefine `document`, but the price would be high.

Comment: @cfr: I have changed `Plain LaTeX` to `LaTeX`. I want to check particular text only like `XXXX` or `YYYY` and not for `LaTeX Commands`. How to redefine the entire `document` using `LaTeX`. Any ideas greatly appreciate.

Comment: (1) How long is your document? (2) How fast is your processor (single thread)? (3) How long are you prepared to wait for each compilation? (4) What do you mean by 'LaTeX'? Just the official 2e commands/environments? Then your task is impossible. Those plus TeX and/or `expl3`? Then your task is merely absurd. Redefining `document` was not a serious suggestion but if you really want an example, look at `standalone` which redefines `document` when called as a package.

Comment: @cfr: I have modified the question. I would like to check particular environment only instead of full LaTeX document (like `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}`). Need to compile `LaTeX filename.tex`. The commands are officlal 2e commands/environments only. The solutions is TeX or expl3 any is OK for me.

Comment: if you want latex to check for this use `\XXX` not `XXX'. if you want to check for the latter use perl or python or similar

Comment: LaTeX never reads the file in to memory so the checks you ask for are not realisticaly feasible in general. If the free text is in a specific controlled enviornment or argument that you can grab in advance it may be possible in some cases but TeX is the completely wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @Kavi did you check the links I posted under your Meta.SE question? These answer your question.

Comment: @Marijn: Sorry, I didn't check and could post again please here...

Comment: Your question sounds like an xy-problem. Can you add a bit more background why you want to replace the text? Maybe this will inspire people to come up with alternative approaches.

Comment: You've changed your question, *after* I've answered the original one. You should not do this! You original question was, how to replace `XXXX` and `ZZZZ` in a `quote` environment. If you now, also want to replace `------` in the bibliography, you should ask a follow-up question = new question. BTW: I looks like the `thebibliography` environment has been generated using BibTeX and a bibliography style, that uses `------` for following entries with the same authors. In this case, I would recommend to change the bibliography style and run bibtex again.

Comment: @cabohah: New Question link is <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705679/read-content-particular-environment-using-latex-only>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to replace tokens inside the `quote` environment, you can redefine it using `\NewEnvironmentCopy` and the argument type `+b`, which represents the body of the environment. Now using `l3` you can replace tokens inside the body by others, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{latexquote}{quote}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__quotebody_tl
\RenewDocumentEnvironment { quote } { +b }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__quotebody_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__quotebody_tl { XXXX } { \LaTeX{}~Compile~Error }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__quotebody_tl { ZZZZ } { \textit{\texttt{ZZZZ}} }
    \latexquote
    \l__quotebody_tl
    \endlatexquote
  }
  {
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\title{Book Title}
\author{Author Name}
\maketitle
    
To address these issues, \textit{WordMelodies} a mobile application to support children in the acquisition of basic literacy skills.
The app was designed to be inclusive for children with and without VIB, thus promoting interaction between them.
\textit{WordMelodies} also supports children in exercising basic touchscreen interactions on mobile devices.

\begin{quote}
    The AI for the expected number of XXXX to ZZZZ transitive triads is generally very narrow. Since this statistic reflects relatively high-order structures (because more ties are involved), its range of possible values given the number of edge counts or mutual.
\end{quote}    

We previously presented a evaluation with visual impairments to assess app usability and accessibility XXXX and ZZZZ.
Study results unveiled that the app is indeed accessible and usable by people with VIB.
After the publication remote collection of app usage data, aiming to investigate how end users interact with the system.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information about `expl3` syntax and LaTeX3 functions like `tl_replace_all:Nnn` (or maybe even `\regex_replace_all:nnN`) see the documentation of the [LaTeX3 kernel](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel).

However, I do not think, that something like this really makes much sense. As David told in a comment: If you want placeholders in your text, that should be replaced, it would make more sense to define these placeholders as macros and use these macros:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand*\XXXX{XXXX}
\newcommand*\ZZZZ{ZZZZ}

\AddToHook{env/quote/begin}{%
  \renewcommand*\XXXX{%
    \GenericError{}
      {LaTeX Error: \string\XXXX\space used}
      {Don't do it.}
      {Usage of \string\XXXX\space inside quote is not allowed.}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*\ZZZZ{\textit{\texttt{ZZZZ}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\title{Book Title}
\author{Author Name}
\maketitle
    
To address these issues, \textit{WordMelodies} a mobile application to support children in the acquisition of basic literacy skills.
The app was designed to be inclusive for children with and without VIB, thus promoting interaction between them.
\textit{WordMelodies} also supports children in exercising basic touchscreen interactions on mobile devices.

\begin{quote}
    The AI for the expected number of \XXXX{} to \ZZZZ{} transitive triads is generally very narrow. Since this statistic reflects relatively high-order structures (because more ties are involved), its range of possible values given the number of edge counts or mutual.
\end{quote}    

We previously presented a evaluation with visual impairments to assess app usability and accessibility \XXXX{} and \ZZZZ{}.
Study results unveiled that the app is indeed accessible and usable by people with VIB.
After the publication remote collection of app usage data, aiming to investigate how end users interact with the system.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I would like to check `\begin{thebibliography}` instead of `\begin{quote}` it's not working. Need to find the text `------`. How to do this updation?

Comment: @Kavi Depends on how the bibliography and the `------` are produced. So I would say, that this is a follow-up question and you should ask it with appropriate MWE. But also see the second part of my answer. In most (or almost all) cases it is much better to use macros instead of placeholder strings.

Comment: I accept your second part is working fine and modified my question also. But in our `LaTeX` file need to find `-----` and show `LaTeX Compile Error` in `\thebibliography` environment. How to do? Thanks for your support and help.