# Read Content particular environment using LaTeX only

Tags: macros

I would like to find the text from `\begin{thebibliography}....\end{thebibliography}` environment text like example `------`(6dashes) using LaTeX2e or LaTeX3 Macros and will show `LaTeX GeneriorError` when compiling:

`LaTeX filename.tex`

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{ragged2e}
        
        \begin{document}
        \title{Book Title}
        \author{Author Name}
        \maketitle
        
    To address these issues, \textit{WordMelodies} a mobile application to support children in the acquisition of basic literacy skills.
    The app was designed to be inclusive for children with and without VIB, thus promoting interaction between them.
    \textit{WordMelodies} also supports children in exercising basic touchscreen interactions on mobile devices.
    
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{bib1}
Author N., ``Revisiting the Foundations of Network Analysis,'' {\em Science}, {325},~414--416.

\bibitem{bib2}
``Diagnosing Multicollinearity ------ Random Graph Models,'' {\em Research}, {50},~491--530.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I had checked [To Read Full LaTeX File using LaTeX2e Macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705284/to-read-full-latex-file-using-latex2e-macros) and not working in `\thebibliography` envirnments.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear whether you want to generate an actual error (in accordance with my admittedly uncertain attempt to understand your question) or whether you want to include something like `LaTeX GenericError` in your typeset output (as the linked answer you accepted suggests). Since you already have code for the latter, I modified [cabohah's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705318/) to provide the former.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705721/ addaswyd o ateb cabohah: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705318/
\NewEnvironmentCopy{thebibliographyorig}{thebibliography}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__kavi_bibbody_tl
\RenewDocumentEnvironment { thebibliography } { +b }
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l__kavi_bibbody_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__kavi_bibbody_tl { ------ } { \PackageError{kavi}{ LaTeX ~ GenericError }{Don't ~ use ~ six ~ hyphens ~ in ~ a ~ row! } }
  \expandafter
  \thebibliographyorig
  \l__kavi_bibbody_tl
  \endthebibliographyorig
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\title{Book Title}
\author{Author Name}
\maketitle

To address these issues, \textit{WordMelodies} a mobile application to support children in the acquisition of basic literacy skills.
The app was designed to be inclusive for children with and without VIB, thus promoting interaction between them.
\textit{WordMelodies} also supports children in exercising basic touchscreen interactions on mobile devices.
    
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{bib1}
Author N., ``Revisiting the Foundations of Network Analysis,'' {\em Science}, {325},~414--416.

\bibitem{bib2}
``Diagnosing Multicollinearity ------ Random Graph Models,'' {\em Research}, {50},~491--530.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```